# Resolving a "paradox" with real continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

> Let
>   $$f\in \mathcal C^0(\mathbb R),\quad f(0)=0,\quad f(a)>0,\quad f(-a)<0,\quad a>0.$$
>
> Let interval $I$ satisfies: 
>   $$\{x\in I\ |\ f(x)=0\}=K,$$ where $K$ is a subinterval, $K\subset I,$ and $0\in K$.
>
> Question: Does such an $I$ always exist for any $f$?
>
> 1. Yes, of course. Let $A=\{x>0|f(x)\neq 0\}$. $A$ must be nonempty. Take its element, $a^*$, to be the closest element to $0$.
>
>    Similarly, let $A'=\{x<0|f(x)\neq0\}$. $A'$ must be nonempty. Take its element, $a'^*$, to be the closest element to $0$. $(a'^*,a^*)$ is the interval we want.
> 2. No. Intuitively, it is easy to construct Weierstrass function $f$ such that $\forall \varepsilon>0$, we have $\{x\in (0,\varepsilon)|f(x)=0\}$ is infinite and discrete.

---

I think $(2)$ is correct (so $(1)$ is wrong), because we can construct a $f$ such that $A$ is a discrete set without minimum, and $\inf (A)=0$. Does this make sense?

---

A related question: Does there exist an interval with singleton interior (here "interior" means topological interior)?

Comment: 1 is wrong because you have no guarantee that $f$ is actually zero on every point of the interval. If you have a potential example for $2$, then try running the argument in (1) with that specific function to see the error. Second question: depends on whether you consider $[a,a]=\{a\}$ an interval, and whether if you do, you consider $a$ to be in the interior.

Comment: In regards to the latter question, an interval with a point as interior has that point alone as boundary, and contains that point, obviously, so a singleton is always a closed set. As to whether to call it an interval, well, I dunno. Intervals are usually meant to indicate the presence of uncountably many points on the line. A single point is obviously countable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you! I though $int(S)=S\setminus bd(S)$, so $int([a,a])$ is empty?

Comment: Like I said: depends on your definitions. Some people consider $[a,a]$ an interval, some do not.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Even if we do consider $[a,a]$ as an interval, then the definition of interior is still the set minus the boundary, I think

Comment: Topological interior is the largest open set contained in the set; if that’s what you meant, then the degenerate interval has empty interior.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes! Thanks for clarification.

Comment: 1 also is wrong because you have no guarantee that the required smallest (or largest) element exists.  What’s the smallest positive number?  What’s the largest negative number?